# Register an instance of a service in Prism.Unity which relies on another service

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, unity-container, prism, ioc-container

I have an authentification service, that I register in my Unity Container like so:

```
Container.RegisterInstance<IAuthenticationService>(new AuthenticationService());
```

My problem is that my `AuthentificationService` relies on `INavigationService`, and its constructor takes this as an argument:

```
public AuthenticationService(INavigationService navigationService)
```

From my understanding, the Unity Container is responsible for injecting the `INavigationService` implementation. But in this case, I am providing the `AuthenticationService` instance, so how can I tell Unity to inject the `INavigationService` in my `AuthentificationService implementation`?

Comment: Updated formatting.

Comment: Why do you have to register an instance? If you registered a type, unity would inject any necessary dependencies into the constructor.

Comment: That is not a thoughtful choice, I am new to IOC and Unity, so I chose the first solution that worked, do you think there is a benefit to register a type over an instance in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first place, you use a DI Container like unity to get rid of `new`. So registering an instance is kind of a last resort, if you're forced to do it.

Normally, you want to register *types*, telling unity *what* to create, leaving the *how* to the container.

You should write

```
Container.RegisterType<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>( new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager() );
```

When it comes to creating the `AuthenticationService` instance, unity will try to resolve all constructor parameters, and pass the `INavigationService` to your `AuthenticationService`:

```
internal class AuthenticationService
{
    public AuthenticationService( INavigationService navigationService )
    {
        // here you've got the Navigation Service...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is unsupported. In order for navigation to work properly Prism's NavigationService requires an understanding of the current Page. The ViewModelLocator handles this and injects an appropriate instance of the Service.

A better way to handle this scenario is to return an Authentication result, and make a determination of how to handle that result in your ViewModel where you can use a properly constructed instance of `INavigationService`.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense, I was trying to implement the same mechanism as a sample Prism application which uses the DryIoc framework, but I see how it can not be done using Unity. I'll return a result in the Authentification service and it will be handled by the ViewModel.